# How to convert integers inside a dataframe to their respective char value using Python Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get this dataframe as output :

```
1    abc
2    def
3    ghi
dtype: object
```

I'm passing integers as dictionary to build this dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

d = {0: {50: 1, 50: 2, 50: 3,}, 1:{23: 1, 23: 2, 23: 3}, 2:{24: 1, 24: 2, 24: 3}}
print (pd.DataFrame(d).pivot(0,1,2))
print (pd.DataFrame(d).pivot(0,1,2).applymap(chr).agg(''.join))
```

The first print shows `Nan` values :

```
1    NaN  3.0
0            
NaN  3.0  NaN
3.0  NaN  NaN
```

The second print shows errors

```
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Can you explain why that structure of the dictionary?

Comment: Structure need not be the same . But the dictionary should only contain integers

Comment: But can you explain what those key values represent?

Comment: i believe asci value of `a`,`b` etc..

Comment: Those aren't the ASCII values for a, b etc. a is 97, b is 98, c is 99 etc.

Comment: I can't see how... `a` is decimal 97, where does that come from?

Comment: Wrong ASCII values is not the problem , that can be fixed . But why arent the `print` statements working ? Is there a fix for that ?

Comment: Your data doesn't make sense. `0: {50: 1, 50: 2, 50: 3,}` has repeated key, and is just `0:{50:3}`. That's why your `pd.DataFrame(d)` has `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first print you get `Nan` values because you have multiple values corresponding to the same key in the inner dictionaries. For example: `{50: 1, 50: 2, 50: 3,}` In such cases it assumes the key '50' to have only the last value, i.e '3'.

Probably, you want something like this:

```
d = {50: {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3,}, 23:{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}, 24:{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}}
print(pd.DataFrame(d))
```

This would give:

```
+----+------+------+------+
|    |   50 |   23 |   24 |
|----+------+------+------|
|  0 |    1 |    1 |    1 |
|  1 |    2 |    2 |    2 |
|  2 |    3 |    3 |    3 |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Now you need to apply `chr` function with an offset of 96 to view the corresponding alphabets, like as follows:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(d).applymap(lambda x:chr(x+96)))
```

Sample output:

```
+----+------+------+------+
|    | 50   | 23   | 24   |
|----+------+------+------|
|  0 | a    | a    | a    |
|  1 | b    | b    | b    |
|  2 | c    | c    | c    |
+----+------+------+------+
```

UPDATE:

You can now use the `agg()` function on this to get the desired result:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(d).applymap(lambda x:chr(x+96)).agg(''.join))
```

Sample Output:

```
50    abc
23    abc
24    abc
```

Comment: Till here i understand , but how do i use `pivot` and `agg.join` functions on this dataframe to get my expected output `df` ? Notice `abc` is joined together. Cause everytime i do that, i get `expected int not float` error

Comment: Could you add the expected dataframe in the question to get a clearer idea?

Comment: Check the update. As the input in the example is 1,2,3 it only provides `abc` as output. Change the indices as required while providing the input dictionary. This is just an example.

Comment: I don't understand why you need `pivot` here.

Comment: yeah you are right, no need for pivot..thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229457/discussion-between-roberj-and-ishwar-venugopal).